# How to add a new attribute in order response json in get order api

Tags: sales-order, rest-api, json, ee-2.2.5

I have added a new column "old_order_id" in sales_order table using upgradeSchema.

Now, I need to set that "old_order_id" through API. So, how to add that attribute(old_order_id) in request json while creating a new order.

And I also need how to add it in fetching order (api: V1/orders/:orderid) response too.